# Remove class from all elements in an SVG?

Tags: jquery, css, svg

Is there a way to remove a class from all elements in an SVG through jQuery and then just add a class to one specific ID?

I'm trying to toggle through elements in an SVG by ID, but I won't know the exact ID as it will be coming from a data-id.

JQUERY

```
  var amenityid = $(this).attr("data-id");
  $('.amenitypage svg').removeClass("highlight");
  $('.amenitypage svg #' + amenityid).addClass("highlight");
```

**UPDATE**: This seems to work for me. If I specify removal by polyline and polygon.

```
$('.amenitypage svg polyline,.amenitypage svg polygon').removeClass("highlight");
$('.amenitypage svg #' + amenityid).addClass("highlight");
```

Comment: When you want to remove the class from everything inside another element this selector could work for you: `$('.amenitypage svg *')`

Answer (score 0):

Well if you remove all elements from the svg then you cannot find the amenity id once you remove them all.

what you can do to empty out everything inside the svg tag is do the below.

```
$('.amenitypage svg').html('');
```

Comment: What has that to do with the question? He asked about removing a class and not removing all elements

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the `.hightlight` class then just targeting that class instead of targeting the element itself might be the easiest like so:

```
$('.highlight').removeClass("highlight");
```

And if you have highlight classes in other elements outside your svg you can just wrap your svg in an id and target that id's highlight classes

```
$('#myElement .highlight').removeClass("highlight");
```

Here is a fiddle [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/0gx778hp/)

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but just figured out how to do it. If you want to remove the class from multiple path elements in an SVG you can use .each and this.classList.remove.

Example:

```
$(".map-path").each(function( index ) {
    this.classList.remove("selected");
});
```